# Get attached file content with XmlHttpRequest and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, text, download, xmlhttprequest

I'm using XmlHttpRequest to perform a text file download, and here is the response header I have got from the server :

```
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="template"
Content-Length: 244
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: 0
Content-Encoding: deflate
Content-Type: application/force-download; name="template"
```

With Firefox or another browser, all is fine: response.responseText contains the text file and I can put it in a text area, but with IE8, responseText is empty.
How to get the response with IE?

Comment: What did your request look like?

Comment: Host: vm-trunk
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; fr; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
  Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
  Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
  Keep-Alive: 115
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
  Referer: https://XXXXX/admin/admin.html
  Cookie: XXXXXXXXX